# Is there a way to more secure a cookie beside the https secure tunnel?

Tags: javascript, php, security, cookies

I have an application where I send the auth token to the server with every request as a cookie in the header request. Also, I force the app to run over `HTTPS`, so cookie headers are encrypted. However, I know that's not enough keep the cookie inaccessible to (XSS) attacks. I thought of the `HttpOnly` option, but that won't help since it can't be accessible by Javascript.

Is there any other options that I can do to better secure the cookie that I send in the header request?

Comment: Read the documentation for `HttpOnly` again. You may have misunderstood what it does…

Answer (score 2):

When using cookie-based authentication, the `HttpOnly` flag is the one you're looking for: when the user logs in, the server sends the `HttpOnly` cookie to the browser, which is not accessible by JavaScript and shouldn't be accessible by JavaScript, the only important part is that the browser will automatically send the cookie to the server for every request matching the domain of the cookie.

What you need to keep in mind is that cookie-based authentication needs an additional mechanism to protect against [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

If, on the other hand, you're using OpenID Connect or OAuth2 authentication and want to store the access token in a cookie, then yes, you can't use `HttpOnly` flag. But it also doesn't make sense to encrypt that cookie with some magic, because if someone can steal the cookie, they'd steal the correctly encrypted cookie which remains valid. The key thing here is, you should protect every input on your website against XSS: if you have text-inputs, you'll have to filter the input against XSS attacks, for PHP you could take a look at the [AntiXSS library](https://github.com/voku/anti-xss). Also don't link to client-side libraries, images or other resources from CDN's you don't trust as scripts could be injected from there too.

For access tokens, no matter what method you're using to store or encrypt it, the access token is always prone to XSS, because your own JavaScript application needs access to it. That's the main reason why an access token is, and should always be, short living (max 1 hour f.e.).